# Creating a Color object for each pixel while using Bitmap.LockBits faster than BitMap.GetPixel?

Tags: .net, performance, bitmap, system.drawing, lockbits

Is creating a `Color` object for each pixel while using `Bitmap.LockBits` still faster than using `Bitmap.GetPixel` for each pixel?

Or maybe creating that `Color` is the main overhead of `Bitmap.GetPixel` as compared to the `LockBits` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color is a struct, not an object.  Overhead is negligible.

GetPixel() is so expensive because it has to lock and unlock the bitmap for each individual pixel.  With LockBits() you can do it only once for the entire bitmap.